# Defining hitArea on Spark ToggleButton

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I've been able to skin a ToggleButton with custom images ([loading Skin images dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27550356/loading-skin-images-dynamically/27552154#27552154)) and it is working well.

The last functionality I would like to add is to limit interactivity (mouseEvents) to the opaque pixels. I've been searching around and came across [InteractivePNG](http://blog.menhir.be/2008/09/28/transparant-png-mouse-events/) and [Creating a hitarea for PNG Image with transparent (alpha) regions in Flex](http://web-verwirklichung.de/en/node/18/). I had erratic results with `InteractivePNG`in initial tests so I thought I would try to define the `ToggleButton` hitArea property using the code from the second link.

I haven't been able to get it working. My code for generating the Sprite to define the hit area is below. (I've also tried just a simple Sprite with a rect drawn within it.) When I set the `togglebutton.hitArea` I don't get any errors but it is no longer interactive.

**Does the Sprite defining the hitArea need to be added to the DisplayList of the object it is being applied to?** If so, how to I do that with a subclass of `ToggleButton`?

```
        hitSprite = createHitArea(upImageData, 1);
        hitSprite.mouseEnabled = false;
        this.hitArea = hitSprite;
```

Of course calling `addChild() on a ToggleButton throws an error.

```
        this.addChild(hitSprite);
```

I've tried:

- wrapping my custom ToggleButton in a Spark Group, and then an MX UIComponent so that I could have a use a SpriteDisplayElement to add things to – but that didn't work.
- adding a Sprite within my custom ToggleButton definition – and get an error doing that.

Am I out of luck here using the ToggleButton class for this type of functionality? What I don't understand is why ToggleButton has a hitArea property if there isn't a way to set it – but that can't be the case so I must be doing something wrong.

**Update**

I just tried this approach( [Flex 4 Custom Component - How to notify skin of property changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067125/840992)) binding to a `SpriteVisualElement` that gets created in to ToggleButton – but still no success in setting the `hitArea` – either of the ToggleButton or the Skin it is using.

---

```
    public function createHitArea(bitmapData:BitmapData, grainSize:uint=1):SpriteVisualElement
        {   
            var _hitarea:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
            _hitarea.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 1.0);         
            for(var x:uint=0;x<bitmapData.width;x+=grainSize) {
                for(var y:uint=grainSize;y<bitmapData.height;y+=grainSize) {                    
                    if(x<=bitmapData.width && y<=bitmapData.height && bitmapData.getPixel(x,y)!=0) {
                        _hitarea.graphics.drawRect(x,y,grainSize,grainSize);                        
                    }                   
                }
            }           
            _hitarea.graphics.endFill();
            _hitarea.cacheAsBitmap = true;
            return _hitarea;
        }
    ]]>
```

Comment: FWIW - after grinding on this for a long time I gave up and just wrote the entire thing in straight actionscript. So much for "rapid development" in Flex. Frustrating, overly complicated and inconsistent docs, bugs and dead ends. I like some of the sugar Flex provides but it costs way, way too much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the `hitArea` property, but I have dealt with buttons that have transparencies.  I solve that by adding something like this to my button skin:

```
    <s:Group id="clickTarget" top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0">
        <s:Rect top="0" left="0" bottom="0" right="0">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.01" />
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:Group>
```

Comment: thanks - yeah, I'm trying to make the transparent areas on my button images non-responsive to mouseEvents. Seemed like `hitArea` is the way to do that but no joy so far.